# php inside of html echo

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

I am having some trouble trying to add an if statement to hide an ACF field inside of an HTML echo.

```
<?php
$link = get_permalink();
$availability = get_field('availability');
$delivery_date = get_field('delivery_date');
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo '<a href="' .$link. '">
            <div class="thumbnail" style="background: url('.$url.')">
                <div class="tags one">
                    <span class="availability">' .$availability. '</span>
                    'if( get_field('delivery_date') ):' <span class="delivery-date">' .$delivery_date. '</span> 'endif;'
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>';
    }
?>
```

Please would someone be able to advise on where I'm going wrong with the if statement to hide the field if it's empty? At the moment it just errors the page.

Comment: ___At the moment it just errors the page.___ So it would be useful if you showed us the error

Comment: The page stops displaying the content. There is no specific error. I assume to code I have applied for the if statement in the echo is incorrect.

Comment: you can't just drop an if statement in the middle of an echoed string.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense now you've mentioned it. I'm still new to all this if you can't tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the PHP code out of the text string, this is one way

```
<?php
$link = get_permalink();
$availability = get_field('availability');
$delivery_date = get_field('delivery_date');
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo '<a href="' .$link. '">
            <div class="thumbnail" style="background: url('.$url.')">
                <div class="tags one">
                    <span class="availability">' .$availability. '</span>';

    if( get_field('delivery_date') ): 
        echo '<span class="delivery-date">' .$delivery_date. '</span>';
    endif;
    echo '</div>
      </div>
    </a>';
}
?>
```